# Yii строка поиска в layout/main

Tags: php, yii

Всем доброго времени суток. Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать такую вещь. У меня есть экшн для поиска(который расширяет CAction)

```
class ActionSearch extends CAction {

    public $model;
    public $view;
    public $field;

    // $data - То что надо искать
    // $field - поле по которому искать
    // $model - класс модели

    public function run() {
        $data = array_shift($_GET);

        if (trim($data) !== null) {

            $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
            $criteria->compare($this->field, $data, true);

            $this->controller->render($this->view, array('dataProvider' => new CActiveDataProvider($this->model, array(
                    'criteria' => $criteria
            ))));
        }
    }
}
```

И форма поиска

```
$model = new Sites('find');

                $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                    'action' => array('admin/site/search'),
                    'method' => 'get',
                    'enableClientValidation'=>true
                ));
                echo 'URL: ';
                echo $form->textField($model, 'url');
                echo $form->error($model, 'url');

                echo CHtml::submitButton('Найти');

                $this->endWidget();
```

Скажите пожалуйста как и где можно делать валидацию всего этого чуда? Всего что я смог добиться это JS валидация на клиенте. А мне нужно ещё на сервере...

Comment: Интересно, для чего вот это: $data = array_shift($_GET) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В твоём случае нет специальной формы поиска, вместо неё ты просто создаёшь виджет-форму. Серверная валидация будет выполняться при вызове

```
new CActiveDataProvider($this->model, array(
    'criteria' => $criteria
));
```

При этом проверяется фильтр, описанный в методе rules экземпляра $model с ключом 'on' => 'search'. Обычно там просто список полей, по которому можно искать.

---

Для валидации данных динамических форм в общем случае используются фильтры, описанные в связанной модели ActiveRecord (описываются в методе rules класса модели)

```
<?php
class AAA extends CActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('field1', 'required'),
            array('field1', 'length', 'max'=>255),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('field1, field2', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }
?>
```

Можно создать модель формы и прописать правила проверки в ней

```
<?
/**
 * LoginForm class.
 * LoginForm is the data structure for keeping
 * user login form data. It is used by the 'login' action of 'SiteController'.
 */
class AAASpecialForm extends CFormModel
{

   public $field3;

    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('field4', 'required'),
            // field4needs to be validated using $this->checkField4()
            array('field4', 'checkField4')
        );
    }

    /**
     * специальная функция проверки для поля field4
     */
    public function checkField4()
    {
        if ($this->field4 != 'someValue') // какая-нибудь проверка
        {
            $this->addError('field4', 'Invalid value'); // сообщение об ошибке в конкретном поле
        }
    }
```

В контролере проверка формы выполняется так:

```
<?php
class BbbController extends CController
{
    public function actionCcc()
    {
        $model = new \AAASpecialForm; // используется модель-форма
        if(isset($_POST['AAASpecialForm'])) // если прислали данные формы
        {
            $model->attributes = $_POST['AAASpecialForm']; // записать сразу все данные в форму
            if($model->validate()) // проверить значения полей формы
            {
                 // тут код, если все поля в форме заполнены корректно
            }
        }

        // отрисовать форму, с ошибками если есть
        $this->render('ссс', array(
            'model' => $model,
        ));
    }
}
```

- [Конструктор форм в Yii](http://habrahabr.ru/post/155127/) на хабре
- [Использование конструктора форм](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/form.builder) в официальной документации Yii
- [Создание модели формы](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/form.model) в официальной документации Yii

Comment: Извините, но вы не поняли. Просто создать форму и проверить её валидатором я могу, но беда в том что это layout, а не какой-то обычный view. А как там проходить валидацию я не знаю.?

Comment: Извините, но вы меня не поняли. Если нужно выполнить валидацию и собрать сообщения об ошибках, но нужна модель формы.

Comment: Вставлять форму именно так именно в layout - это неправильно. В layout идёт работа с макетом страницы, в отдельных местах, где нужна интерактивность, вызываются виджеты.

Comment: [виджет поиска по сайту][1]

 [1]: http://loco.ru/materials/140-yii-site-search

Comment: @Angus123, c точки зрения валидации нет абсолютно никакой разницы, где форма располагается.